# openni_tracker fails on 12.04

Tags: openi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

http://answers.ros.org/question/42654/openninite-incompatible-in-fuerteprecise/

According to above, this should been fixed with 1.5.4.0 according to @tfoote but I am still seeing it on Fuerte/Groovy on 12.04.

```
[ERROR]: Find user generator failed: This operation is invalid!
```

And I tried the workaround proposed by @pgorczak in there but it no longer works.

Has anyone found another workaround or know how to fix it? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55761/openni_tracker-fails-on-12.04/) by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) on ROS Answers with karma: 212 on 2013-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For me the workaround worked. It was sufficient to install the linux version of NITE-dev v1.5.2.21 and the error disappeared.

---

Originally posted by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) with karma: 620 on 2013-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) on 2013-02-20**:
If you take a look at http://www.openni.org/openni-sdk/openni-sdk-history-2/, there are 3 different things. I installed "OpenNI SDK v1.5.4.0", am I supposed to install just "NiTE v1.5.2.21" or all three?

**Comment by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) on 2013-02-20**:
I was installing the wrong thing. Installing "NITE v1.5.2.21" made it work. (It is the last one at that link) Just ran "sudo ./uninstall.sh" and "sudo ./install.sh". Thanks!

**Comment by [jys](https://answers.ros.org/users/3404/jys/) on 2013-02-21**:
@rastaxe could you take a look at my new question http://answers.ros.org/question/55827/openni_tracker-displaying-pointcloud-and-skeleton-alignment/ Thanks!

**Comment by [shivesh_sk](https://answers.ros.org/users/18061/shivesh_sk/) on 2014-05-16**:
Hi, I am facing the same problem and have installed NiTE v1.5.2.21 but it still shows the same error for me. I am using ROS Groovy with Ubuntu 12.04. Any help would be appreciated.

**Comment by [rastaxe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2870/rastaxe/) on 2014-11-14**:
In my experience, this method works only on 32 bit, have you a 64 bit? In this case, you have to try openni2_tracker.